# Vercel/Pkg + Regedit

Tags: node.js, vercel, regedit

> I am using regedit library with pkg library to compile the code to exe.
> But I get error "Error: vbscript process reported unknown error
> code 1"
> I tried to do that
> "regedit.setExternalVBSLocation(os.tmpdir());"
>
> Please help me